# How to convert image file to greyscale and save it in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are some discussions on how to make it appear greyscale in-place (which can be done through using [this](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters)), but that won't help with saving converted images to disk. Is writing custom native modules or doing it manually by manipulating pixel values are the only options? All react-native libraries I've found do not support this.